# Mysql Query to Merge 3 tables into 1 Table

Tags: mysql

TO Plot Each Input table I have Separate query, need to apply functionality on that queries and want to create Single query  for Output Table

Select Distinct Names, SUM(count) from 
(Select Query  table 1 
union 
Select Query  table 2
union
Select Query  table 3) table group by Names;

this query Not adding count properly Niether Sorting Names properly Whats wrong with this ?

Input Table 1 :-

```
    Names count  
    bob   3
    pol   4
```

Input Table 2 :-

```
    Names count    
    bob   5  
          0      - name may be missing here neglect this entry
```

Input Table 3 :-

```
    Names count  
    james  4  
    pol    7  
    bob    1
```

Expected output table :-

```
    Names  count  
    bob    9  
    pol    11  
    james  4
```

Comment: Please show some effort and explain what you have tried. SO is not a query writing service.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  of coarse it is not query writing service ..  to plot each table i have diffrent query i need to combine that query for final result and this tables are just examples

Comment: i tried with union all distinct inner join after taking all efforts it didn't worked , that's why i am asking this question this way

Comment: Then please edit the question, explain what you tried, what was wrong with them etc.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION and them sum of those.

```
        select sum(a), sum(b) from 
    (select 2 as a, 1 as b 
union select 3 as a, 6 as b 
union select 4 as a, 1 as b) as b
```

Comment: i  am not getting :(

Comment: I just added a sample query with union and sum. You need to do the same on you mail tables to get the name and count accordingly in the sub queries.

Comment: i tried with same earlier it is not working with union and sum

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select `Name`,sum(`Count`) total from ( select `Name`,`Count` from `table1` union all select `Name`,`Count` from `table2` union all select `Name`,`Count` from `table3` ) tot group by `Name`
```

May this help you.

Comment: it is returning names names names under name column

Comment: I am created table on my system as you mention and it runs properly. Can you show me how you run query?